# hostedDomain with Angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In angularfire, prior to angularfire2, you are able to set custom parameters (e.g. hosted domain) for a google auth provider like this:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  hd: "example.com"
});
```

how do you do the same in angularfire2?

regards
Adisa

Comment: anyone?  All am trying to do is implement what google describes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is not supported by angularfire2.

I ended up using firebase.js directly.